# Java Difference methods

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to create a method that checks the 1st differences of some Y coordinates and if the 1st differences are the same it will take those differences and check for the 2nd differences, and I want to keep checking until my variable are equal.  My problem is checking for the equality in my array of Differences

```
public static double[] Difference(double ardY[]) {
    double ardDifference[] = new double[5];
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        ardDifference[j] = ardY[j + 1] - ardY[j];
        while (ardDifference[j] != ardDifference[j]) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                ardDifference[i] = ardY[i + 1] - ardY[i];
                if (ardDifference[j] == ardDifference[i]) {
                    return ardDifference;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ardDifference;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? It's vague..

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: You may want to post a short data example of your method: what it gets and what it returns.

Comment: `while (ardDifference[j] != ardDifference[j])` will always be false

Comment: For one thing, it won't compile because of the `break` following the return statement.  That should be removed.

Comment: Specifically what do you mean by equal? Two double values that are not copies of eachother will rarely be equal even if they are generated through the same procedure if they are doubles. Are you trying to test whether two values are identical?

Comment: My problem is that the check for equality within the array of differences isn't happening

Comment: Yes, I'm checking to see if they're identical

Comment: You should never compare floating point numbers; better to see if absolute value of their difference is less than a tolerance.

Comment: I am sorry I still don't know what it is you are trying to do. A sample input > output would tell us more than your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you're trying to do here, but if you want to compute differences until you get an array of differences that are all equal then you can do that pretty easily with recursion :

```
public static double[] Difference(double ardY[]) {
    double ardDifference[] = new double[ardY.length - 1];

    boolean allEqual = true;
    double prev;
    for (int j = 0; j < ardDifference.length; j++) {
        ardDifference[j] = ardY[j + 1] - ardY[j];
        if (j != 0) {
            allEqual &= prev == ardDifference[j];
        }
        prev = ardDifference[j];
    }

    if (allEqual) {
        return ardDifference;
    } else {
        return Difference(ardDifference);
    }
}
```